# Javascript redirect vs form submit to a php script

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, pagespeed

I've got a form on my websites homepage that contains a box for a user to enter a members name. From there the form currently submits to a PHP script which just calls `Header('Location: blah);` and then directs them to /search/username/.

Would it be worth it (i'm assuming so) doing that redirection in javascript so that directs them straight to /search/username? If so how would I go about redirecting with javascript, just plain old `window.location = "http://www.google.com/"`

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/how-to-post-forms-to-clean-rewritten-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side is always better method as it's more difficult to bypass than client side method. 
Be sure to add exit function after redirection using header.

```
ob_clean();
header('Location: target.php');
exit();
```

Comment: +1 In addition to the fact that it would completely fail if JS is disabled by the user.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in JavaScript, you could:

```
<input id="username" type="text" onclick="" />
<input type="button" onclick="window.location='/search/'+document.getElementById('username').value" />
```

You could add some validation to the event as well.

> Would it be worth it

That depends on your specific situation. If your server is getting 100's of these requests a second, then sure. Otherwise, it really doesn't matter which way you do it.